# Fetch all values from database and foreach through them

Tags: php, sql, magento

I am using a script to update prices. So far it gets the data from a CSV and uses this to look up in the database and updates the products with the information form the CSV for that row.

The problem I am having is that the SKU's in the CSV don't match exactly to what they are in Magento. For example in the CSV there may be `1234` however in magento the products that need to update with the info on this row would be `001234_01` and `001234_02` and `001234_03` and so on.

So I have added a `LIKE` search to get all the results from Magento that are like the SKU for that row in the CSV.

The problem is that it only finds one updates it and then moves onto the next row. So it will update `001234_01` but I need it to also update `001234_02` and `001234_03` before moving onto the next row.

I think I will need to tweak the _updatePrices to kind of foreach through but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

    /***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
    function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
    }

    function _getTableName($tableName){
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
    }

    function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                    FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
                WHERE
                    entity_type_id = ?
                    AND attribute_code = ?";
        $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
    }

    function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
    }

    function _getIdFromSku($sku){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku LIKE '%$sku%'";
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));

    }

    function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT * FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku LIKE '%$sku%'";
        // I think you can try $conn->fetchAll();
        return $connection->fetchAll($sql, array($sku));
        // print_r this - it will be an array (empty or not)
        print_r($connection);
    }

    function _updatePrices($data){
        $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
        $sku            = $data[0];
        $newPrice       = $data[4];
        $specialPrice   = $data[6];
        $status         = $data[10];
        $productId      = $row['entity_id'];
        $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

        $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $productId));

        $sql2 = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql2, array($specialPrice, '567', $productId));

        if ($status == "A") {
            $sql3 = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql3, array('1', '273', $productId));
        } else {
           $sql4 = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql4, array('2', '273', $productId));
        }

    }
    /***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

    // Here comes your code after UTILITY FUNCTIONS:
    $csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
    $data               = $csv->getData('price-update/PRDAH014.csv'); //path to csv
    array_shift($data);

    $message = '';
    $count   = 1;
    foreach($data as $_data){
        // insted of checking if there exists nuber of rows         
        // if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
        // you get rows that match your LIKE query
        $skuRows = _checkIfSkuExists($_data[0]);

        if(0 < sizeof($skuRows)){
            // okay you have records, let's iterate through them
            foreach ($skuRows as $row) {
                try{


                    // modify your _updatePrices so as to use record ID from $row and CSV data from $data both
                    _updatePrices($_data, $row);

                } catch(Exception $e){
                    // exception warning
                }
            }
        }else{
            // no records warning
        }
    } // foreach($data as $_data) ends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your function `_checkIfSkuExists($sku)` should return **not count of rows** but rows themselves:

```
function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku LIKE '%$sku%'";

    // I think you can try $conn->fetchAll();
    return $connection->fetchAll($sql, array($sku));
    // print_r this - it will be an array (empty or not)
}
// in each row's data there's a record (or row) ID

function _updatePrices($data, $row){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newPrice       = $data[4];
    $specialPrice   = $data[6];
    $status         = $data[10];
    // here - you don't need to find `entity_id`, you already have it in $row
    //$productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $productId        = $row['entity_id'];
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

   // all your code remains the same
   // ....
} // function _updatePrices ends

// ....

// Here comes your code after UTILITY FUNCTIONS:
$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('price-update/PRDAH014.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    // insted of checking if number of rows that 
    // match your LIKE query is greater than zero
    // if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
    // you get rows themselves that match your LIKE query
    $skuRows = _checkIfSkuExists($_data[0]);
    if(0 < sizeof($skuRows)){
        // okay you have records, let's iterate through them
        foreach ($skuRows as $row) {
            try{
                // modify your _updatePrices so as to use record ID from $row and CSV data from $data both
                _updatePrices($_data, $row);

            } catch(Exception $e){
                // exception warning
            }
        }
    }else{
        // no records warning
    }
    $count++;
} // foreach($data as $_data) ends
// ...
```

I'm not familiar to Magento, but the algorythm is something like this, I think.

Comment: im not really sure how to get it to work as you have stated in your comments how would I get $rows_data is this an array or SKU's that match?

Comment: `$rows_data` is array of SKU's that match your LIKE query.

Comment: I think there should be method `$connection->fetchAll(...);` or something similar which allows you to fetch query results as array.

Comment: Im still a little confused as how to get this and then how and where is $skuRows defined, sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Now i modify the comment) Look)

Comment: Ok thanks now I get `Notice: Undefined variable: rows_data ` so do I somehow need to get these into array e.g `$rows_data = $sql` or something?

Comment: Search for some methods in Magento which allow you to getch sql-query result as array, there definitely should be some.

Comment: Like I supposed there's a method `$conn->fetchAll($sq1);` Now functions will look like (see comment)

Comment: I have added in the new code but it still seems to only update the first match it makes, what do I need to modify in _updatePrices to use the record ID from `$row`? It odes seem to have got all the matches when I `var_dump($row)` so I need to get this into the _updatePrices function to update each one?

Comment: Okay, let's see, Can you add 2 or 3 rows from `$skuRows` to your question so I could see what data fields are in them?

Comment: But I don't think I need it. I think you should modify `_updatesPrices` in the next way, see comment again)

Comment: I added that in but then nothing updates not even the first match

Comment: And do you add second parameter to function call in `try-catch` block?

Comment: yes I added in `($_data, $row)` I have updated my question to reflect all the changes so far

Comment: Strange. Try to check if `_updatePrices` works and `var_dump` each `$row` that is passed there.

Comment: I dont think `$row¬ is being passed as the second paramater if I have `($_data, $row) the script runs if I have `($row, $_data)` it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, if you call `_updatePrices($_data, $row)` it should work. `var_dump($row)` in a function `_updatePrices`, does it shows something?

Comment: @m_ulder my mistake missed the argument in the fucntion! thanks :)